# How to switch theme over category in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, css, zend-framework, zend-view

first, I don't need to "switch" layout.

I'm speaking of CSS theme, that means the layout remains the same.

What I need to do is switch a css class when on certains category.

Category are defined by the route (name & id in request params)

So I think of a ViewHelper, used in my `layout.phtml` to set a `<body class="theme-category"></body>`

But I'll to access the request object in my view helper, is it possible? Is it best practice?

Secondly I though to use the same process but pass the parameters in my controller, and fallback on a default one in my helper if none provided.

What are you feedbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your layout put this

```
<?=$this->headLink(); ?>
```

And in the controllers you can add a specific css file like this

```
$this->view->headLink()->appendStylesheet("/css/file.css");
```

That will enable you to change the css theme on every controller.
P.S. add it in the init function of the controller.

Comment: the css file is the same everywhere, in fact I'll use a contextual body class to apply correct style. .blue .link or .default .link

Comment: you could separate the themes into different css files that will have the desired effect.

Comment: I think it's overhead I want to use minification and cache, a single css file is much better imho

Comment: You could always extend the view helper class to do the minification and caching.

Answer (score 0):

What about a helper method that will just returns the css class, you call this one from your controller, and just pass the css value to the view ?

```
class YourController {
  public function yourpageAction(){
    // do your stuff, then call your helper
    $this->view->bodyCssClass = $this->setcss();
  }

  protected function setcss(){
    // analyse here all the parameter you wish (route, name, id etc.)
    // and just return the correct css string
    return $css;
  }
}
```

You may even use the "init()" method to call automatically your "setcss" method (or whatever the name you give it).
To go further you may extend the Zend Controller class, and have all you controller extend your specific controller : all pages will inherit this css defining process. And it helps to maintain and read your code.

And in your view, just a simple call :

```
<body class="<?php echo $this->bodyCssClass;">
```

Comment: yes it was my second ideas, but that's not about one controller, but several, so I'll to rewrite over all used controller, maybe a action helper will make sense here?

Comment: Nope, just extend ZF's base controller, include a call to your setcss() class in a init() method. Then just have your controllers extends this new controller. Almost no rewrite. Do you want me to detail a bit more in my answer ?

Comment: I don't think extending Zf controller for such a thing is a good ideas for this kind of specific function http://devzone.zend.com/article/3350 Action helpers seems to provide a similar way without extending the controller

Comment: Indeed, the choice is yours. The result is quite similar. Not much code to rewrite and easy to maintain. :)